# date issue in flex due to time zone difference

Tags: apache-flex

I am having problem with dates in flex 3.0 as my client and server are in different zone.
Before using any of the various tweaks, can some one tell me if there's any config we can do , so that flex displays the data as sent to it.
eg:
if server sends 24th oct 2011 6p.m it should display 24th oct 2011 6p.m, irrespective of which time zone you are in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your service layer, normalize dates to UTC.

On clients, apply a timezone offset by adding their offset to the UTC date.  It will display time on client computers accounting for their Time Zone / Daylight Savings.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#timezoneOffset